# Ubuntu 17.10 version gives black screen with TeamViewer access

Tags: 17.10, teamviewer

I recently updated my Ubuntu version to latest one 17.10. Everything works fine but when I try to access my system through TeamViewer it gives me black screen not able to see anything apart from that.

When I was looking for the online solution I got this link https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Linux/Ubuntu-17-10-black-screen/m-p/16429#M690.

As per the above link conversations TeamViewer needs to get the driver updated which can support the latest version of Ubuntu OS.

Any idea about this when can it be done or any other solution to get this sorted out?

Suggestions Please!

Comment: I got it solved with the below solution :    `Please follow below instructions:
- run the command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`
then it will prompt a dialogue box to select the configuration which you want to  access i.e `lightdm`
and restart your system  and select `Ubuntu xorg` in the settings icon  before you login to system`